# How to access custom properties of state views?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this state defined:

```
.state('app.feedback', {
        url: '/feedback',
        views: {
            'appContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/feedback.html',
                controller: 'feedbackCtrl',
                customParameter: 'This is my Name'
            }
        }
    })
```

I'm trying to show that `customParameter`on `appContent`.

This is my controller:

```
.controller('feedbackCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$log', '$state',
 function($scope, $log, $state) {

    $scope.customParameter = $state.current.customParameter;

}]);
```

and this is my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{customParameter}}">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>{{customParameter}}</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Nothing gets showed on the view, when I use a custom parameter without a view object on the state declaration it works, but I will need to have several views in this project. How can I access that custom parameter?

Ps: I'm working with Ionic 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rute I used to try to fetch the param was wrong. I needed to dig more in the `$state` object to find the correct way.

All the parameters are inside `$state.current`

A made a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/CxZXYTSxx0PTVrvvUjFl/) with an example (based on the ionic starter side menu)

The state:

```
 .state('app.playlists', {
      url: "/playlists",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "playlists.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl',
          menuContentParam:'menuContentParam'
        },
        viewsParam:'viewsParam'
      },
      stateParam:'stateParam'
    });
```

The Controller

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
 $scope.stateParam = $state.current.stateParam;
    $scope.viewsParam = $state.current.views.viewsParam;
    $scope.menuContentParam = $state.current.views.menuContent.menuContentParam;
})
```

And the view:

```
<ion-view title="Playlists">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>{{stateParam}}</ion-item>
      <ion-item>{{viewsParam}}</ion-item>
      <ion-item>{{menuContentParam}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use state params to pass the custom data to the state

```
.state('app.feedback', {
    url: '/feedback',
    views: {
        'appContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/feedback.html',
            controller: 'feedbackCtrl'
        }
    },
    params:{
     customParameter: 'This is my Name'
    }
})
```

In Controller use $stateParams to get the customParameter

```
.controller('feedbackCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$log', '$state', $stateParams
 function($scope, $log, $state, $stateParams) {

    $scope.customParameter = $stateParams.customParameter;

}]);
```

And the view is

```
<ion-view view-title="{{customParameter}}">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>{{customParameter}}</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Actually when I see the $stateParams object it is empty, I think it work just with url made params.